# submit handler not working when using hook_form_alter

Tags: forms

I am using hook_form_alter to add validation and submit handlers to the registration form:

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'blah_register_validate';
    $form['#submit'][] = 'blah_register_submit';
  }
}
?>
```

They were both working fine until I added the following hook:

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_user_login(&$edit, $account) { 
  drupal_goto('user');  
}
?>
```

The validation function still works but the submit function gets bypassed completely - it doesn't get called at all by form_execute_handlers() in form.inc. As soon as I remove hook_user_login, it works again. Anyone have an idea why?

**Update:**

hook_user_login() gets called by user_login_finalize() in the User Module. Unfortunately,  this happens before my submit function gets called - so obviously when I use drupal_goto() the submit function will never get called. Can anyone confirm if I am adding the submit handler correctly, is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out [`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/drupal_goto) you can see it calls [`drupal_exit()`](http://api.drupal.org/drupal_exit) which is not something you want to do in a hook. The comments for [`hook_user_login()`](http://api.drupal.org/hook_user_login#comments) discuss this a little, finishing with this snippet:

```
function mymodule_user_login(&$edit, $account)
{
  // Your logic will set $redirection to the desired location
  $redirection = 'node/394';

  // Unless there is already a redirection going, or the user is trying to reset his password, we redirect to $redirection.
  if (empty($_GET['destination'])
    && !is_null($redirection)
    && (!isset($_POST['form_id']) || $_POST['form_id'] != 'user_pass_reset'))
  {
    $_GET['destination'] = $redirection; // Should we use $edit['redirect'] instead..?
  }
}
```

Also mentioned is the [login destination module](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination).

Comment: This is the right answer: As many other hooks, `hook_user_login()` is not supposed to call `drupal_goto()`, which would stop other hooks (and other form handlers) from being executed.

Answer (score 1):

read about [drupal_get_destination](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_destination/7) function. *Used to direct the user back to the referring page after completing a form*.

You should try something like this(*If I understand the question*) :
 `drupal_goto('user', array('query'=>drupal_get_destination()) );`

If you trying to add a *new* Submit handler to an existing `user_login_form` you should try this:

```
 $form['new_submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit',
        '#submit' => array('blah_register_submit'),//name of your submit function
    );
```

Comment: Ah sorry, maybe I didn't explain my problem very clearly. The problem is that my submit function is being called 'after' hook_user_login. So if I add drupal_goto, the page redirects and the submit function doesn't get called at all. So nothing to do with the destination GET variable.

Comment: This plain wrong: To add a submission handler to an existing submission button, you don't add a new submission button.